# Extracting coordinates of text using PDFQuery when multiple instances of that text exist on a single PDF page

Tags: python, pdf

I have some PDF files of laboratory reports which I'm hoping to extract information from using Python. These reports come from a wide range of organisations and have a number of different formats, so it is impractical to manually input in the coordinates of the bbox for results text. Unfortunately the PDF's contain identifying information so I'm unable to post them here, but a screenshot of the section I'm having issues querying is attached.

[image: example test report]

I need to look up various results that are in the "Result" column and was planning to extract the y coordinates of the relevant test result (e.g. Linear Shrinkage) and use this with the x coordinate of the "Result" column label.

I have tried using PDFQuery per the below which works, but it picks up on the first instance of the string "Result" in the label 'Other Test Results' which is unhelpful to me.

```
from pdfquery import PDFQuery

pdf = PDFQuery('example.pdf')
pdf.load(0)
keyword = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:contains("{}")'.format("Result"))[0]
x0 = float(keyword.get('x0',0)) 
y0 = float(keyword.get('y0',0))
x1 = float(keyword.get('x1',0)) 
y1 = float(keyword.get('y1',0))
```

Is there a way to restrict the contains lookup to a certain bounding box, or export xy coordinates of multiple instances of the same string? The location of the "Result" string I'm looking for may be in many places on the page but will always be below "Other Test Results" and along the same y alignment as the "Description", "Method" and "Limits" headers (of which there are also multiple instances on the page)

Apologies if this question is unclear, I'm not a professional developer.

Comment: If you are not bound to using PDFQuery, then [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) is probably the best solution for you. It lets you search for text like that table header line, single words, etc. Also extracts text coordinates and all its font properties (boldness, color and what not). Pls drop me a note.